# Displaying a Constantly Changing Python Variable in HTML

Tags: python, html, sockets, server, raspberry-pi3

I am building a car server with Raspberry Pi 3.

I am reading the speed variable from serial ports using Python.
This variable continuously changes as the car speed changes.

I want to display that value live, in a HTML file.
How can I do this?

I tried creating a text file from the Python script which constantly overwrites a speed.txt and prints on the HTML but as I read it is not secure and fast enough for monitoring.

Comment: Would you be able to provide the python code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Html page must be dynamic and communicate with a web server.
You have 2 options for updating the car speed :

1. use XHR and read the speed periodically from the web server
2. use websocket and let the server push the latest speed to your page.

You can use a framework like Flask for both options